# Adjust image properties with AddPicture Method word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to edit the properties of an image inserted by AddPicture method.

1) I need to adjust the height to 0.5" and the width is variable (lock the aspect ratio).

2) Wrap text = "In Front of Text"

Is this possile with this method? If so how do I add those properties? If not, what other method should I use and how?

```
Sub replaceWithImage()

Dim imageFullPath As String
Dim FindText As String
imageFullPath = "C:\Logo.jpg"
FindText = "PlaceHolder"

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .text = FindText
        ' Loop until Word can no longer
        ' find the search string, inserting the specified image at each location
        Do While .Execute
            Selection.MoveRight
            Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imageFullPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        Loop

    End With
End With


    End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried with macrorecorder?

Comment: Yes. Does not respond for height change and does not allow the change for wrapping text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do what you need in the following steps:

1. instead of this line:

   ```
   Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imageFullPath,  _
                              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
   ```
2. I would do the same but using `Object Variable`:

   ```
   'a) create new shape as object variable
   Dim SHP 'As InlineShape/As Shape
   Set SHP = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=imageFullPath, _
                               LinkToFile:=False, _
                               SaveWithDocument:=True)
   'b) changes made according to SHP varialbe:
   With SHP
       'this will convert to 'in front of text'
       .ConvertToShape
       'this will keep ratio
       .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
       'this will adjust width to 0.5 inch
       .Width = InchesToPoints(0.5)
   End With
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to figure this out for a long time. Much thanks

Comment: Any ideas on how to adjust/move the image to a specific location (left,right) ?

Comment: you should be able to work with `SHP.Left = x` and `SHP.Top = y`. Try something like this...

Comment: It's in inches but what if I need milimeters or centimeters? "Centimerestopoints" doesn't work

Comment: @Eduards, are you sure that such a code doesn't produce any value: `Application.CentimetersToPoints(100)`

Comment: Now it does with "application." Thanks